# How to let other threads to continue on locking elements inside for loop java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Let's say I have below code

```
public class ContinueIfCannotLock implements Runnable
{

static List<LockingObject> lockObjects = new ArrayList();
@Override
   public void run()
   {
       for(LockingObject obj : lockObjects)
       {
           synchronized ( obj )
           {
            // do things here
           }
       }

   }

}
```

and the LockingObject is just and empty class. Also let's assume before these threads start we have 100 of objects in the LockingObject list.
So how can I let a thread to continue to next object in the list if it cannot acquire the lock to the current element. So that no thread (at least until all the objects are not locked by a thread) is waiting inside the loop.

Comment: Basically, you use another type of lock (from the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package) rather than the old `synchronized` structure. Please research the new concurrency tools available (`java.util.concurrent` and `java.util.concurrent.locks`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Thread.holdsLock(Object obj)`,

> Returns true if and only if the current thread holds the monitor lock on the specified object.
>
> <sup>~[Thread (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock-java.lang.Object-)~</sup>

---

```
static List<LockingObject> lockObjects = new ArrayList();
@Override
   public void run(){
       for(LockingObject obj : lockObjects){

           if(Thread.holdsLock(obj)){
               continue; //continue the loop if object is locked.
           }

           synchronized(obj){
               // do things here
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: ela. U r Welcome. :D

Answer (score 1):

You May use locks:

```
static List<ReentrantLock> lockObjects;
public static void init(){
   lockObjects = new ArrayList<>(100);
   for(int i = 0; i<100;i++){
      lockObjects.add(new ReentrantLock());
   }
}
@Override
public void run()
{
    for(LockingObject lock : lockObjects)
    {
        if(lock.tryLock()){
           try{ 
              //dostuff
           }finally{
               lock.unlock();
           }

           // break if you only want the thread to work once
           break;
        }
    }

}
```

If your only goal with this was to have a maximum of 100 threads working at the same time, you could also use a `Semaphore` which is a lock that let's multiple threads lock it up to a specified value.

Comment: So you mean if in this for loop if try lock fails it goes to next lock object?

Comment: yes, since the for cycle will try again with the next object and so on utnil the list ends or it finds one that is not locked